# How do i pass a type name to a function?

Tags: c++, function, typename

My problem is that i can't pass a type name to a function. 
I don't really know how to do it, so i ask myself if that's even possible, but i guess so.

So i want to create a function which accepts type names like sizeof() does.

```
sizeof(int); // accepts a type name not a var
```

My code for trying to realize this looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

void foo( WHAT TO PUT HERE? ) {...};
int main(){
    foo(float);
    return EXIT_SUCCES;
}
```

Basically my problem is that i don't know how to make the function foo accepting type names like sizeof(), What to put in the declaration to make it accepting type names?

Thank your for reading and helping me.

Comment: This is not possible, `sizeof` is a operator, not a function. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: How do you expect to work with whatever your function would receive?

Comment: May be use a template? `template<typename T> void foo() { ... }`

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator in the language, it's handled by the compiler. However, you could maybe do something with templates, but its hard to say since your question is an example of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: the type name passed to the function should change the type of the return value, thats why i need it to be passed to the functiuon

Comment: If you describe what problem you are trying to solve we can suggest an alternative. It looks like a simple template function would work for you.

Comment: If you want to change the return type, you can do something like `template<typename T> T foo();`

Answer (score 6):

First of all `sizeof` is not a function, but an operator (processed only during compilation), and you can't create own operators.

What you probably need is "meta-function" - template.

```
template <typename T>
void foo() { ... /* Use T as type, ex. sizeof(T) */ ... }
```

and call it: `foo<MyType>()`

do remember - all template parameters etc are resolved at *compile* time, there's no way to pass type at runtime in C++ (at least any type)

Return type can be either specified as template parameter (`T foo()`), derived from T (`typename T::return_type foo()`) - if you prepare T properly, or you can provide template specialization for types you need (`template <> float foo<int>()` to return floats for `foo<int>` calls)

If you **really** need you can then create macro to hide template `#define fooCall(X) foo<X>()`. But please - **do not do it**, code should clearly state what it does and *when* it does it. Difference between `<>` and `()` show to readers, when code is evaluated at runtime and when on compile time.

Comment: specialize for the types you need and you're game.

Comment: @Brogramer The missing piece of information here is what you would like to achieve with `foo`, do you want it to return a value or a derived type? Depending on this you may need either a template function or a metafunction.

Comment: Now it works *-* wow thank you, but is there a way i can pass it in () and not like foo<type>();

Comment: @Brogramer no, you can't create function that could be called like `foo(int)`. It has to clearly state it arguments are processed during compilation, `()` suggests runtime evaluation.

Comment: You *could* write a macro so that you can do `foo(int)`, but you shouldn't.